# Live Coding in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

In .NET Core we can run the project wihtout debugging, then make some changes to controllers or models and those changes applied directly without rebuild the project and run it again.

Is this possible in .NET MVC 5 ? if yes HOW ?!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there is a command like `dotnet watch run` that'll let you do this

Comment: I tried this command, but it just worked for .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible in .net MVC you just need to use `dotnet watch run` and you be good to go, but in many cases it just don't work and you need to restart your application anyway.

Comment: I tried this command, but it just worked for .Net Core